# Why does a triggered building always need approval or decline in Drone?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, drone.io

I had created a new gitlab project copied from an existed project. After i commit sth to the new project, Drone successfully received the event, and a new building triggered, but always need confirm, approve or decline.

Drone Project settings:

```
Project Settings:
  Protected
  Trusted
  Auto cancel pull requests

Project Visibility:
  Internal
```

Drone Project Template:

```yaml
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: DEV-Build
image_pull_secrets:
  - docker-config
steps:
  - name: install
    image: enjo-docker-registry-registry.cn-hangzhou.cr.aliyuncs.com/deployment/node:16-alpine-yrm
    pull: if-not-exists
    commands:
      - yrm test `yrm current`
      - yarn
      - ${CMD:=''}
    volumes:
      - name: node_modules
        path: /drone/src/node_modules
  - name: build
    image: enjo-docker-registry-registry.cn-hangzhou.cr.aliyuncs.com/deployment/node:16-alpine-yrm
    pull: if-not-exists
    commands:
      - npm run build_dev
      - rm -rf /tmp/${DRONE_COMMIT}
      - mkdir /tmp/${DRONE_COMMIT}
      - mv dist/ /tmp/${DRONE_COMMIT}/
    volumes:
      - name: tmp
        path: /tmp
      - name: node_modules
        path: /drone/node_modules
volumes:
  - name: node_modules
    host:
      path: /var/lib/cache/node_modules
  - name: tmp
    host:
      path: /tmp/
trigger:
  branch:
    - dev
  event:
    - push
    - custom
node:
  env: dev
---
kind: pipeline
type: exec
name: DEV-Deploy
clone:
  disable: true
steps:
  - name: upload
    commands:
      - cd /tmp/${DRONE_COMMIT}
      - ossutil64 rm -rf oss://{{.input.app_name}}-dev/
      - ossutil64 cp -rf ./dist/ oss://{{.input.app_name}}-dev/
trigger:
  branch:
    - dev
  event:
    - push
    - custom
node:
  env: dev
depends_on:
  - DEV-Build
---
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: TEST-Build
image_pull_secrets:
  - docker-config
steps:
  - name: install
    image: enjo-docker-registry-registry.cn-hangzhou.cr.aliyuncs.com/deployment/node:16-alpine-yrm
    pull: if-not-exists
    commands:
      - yrm test `yrm current`
      - yarn
      - ${CMD:=''}
    volumes:
      - name: node_modules
        path: /drone/src/node_modules
  - name: build
    image: enjo-docker-registry-registry.cn-hangzhou.cr.aliyuncs.com/deployment/node:16-alpine-yrm
    pull: if-not-exists
    commands:
      - npm run build_test
      - rm -rf /tmp/${DRONE_COMMIT}
      - mkdir /tmp/${DRONE_COMMIT}
      - mv dist/ /tmp/${DRONE_COMMIT}/
    volumes:
      - name: tmp
        path: /tmp
      - name: node_modules
        path: /drone/node_modules
volumes:
  - name: node_modules
    host:
      path: /var/lib/cache/node_modules
  - name: tmp
    host:
      path: /tmp/
trigger:
  branch:
    - test
  event:
    - push
    - custom
node:
  env: test
---
kind: pipeline
type: exec
name: TEST-Deploy
clone:
  disable: true
steps:
  - name: upload
    commands:
      - cd /tmp/${DRONE_COMMIT}
      - ossutil64 rm -rf oss://{{.input.app_name}}-test/
      - ossutil64 cp -rf ./dist/ oss://{{.input.app_name}}-test/
trigger:
  branch:
    - test
  event:
    - push
    - custom
node:
  env: test
depends_on:
  - TEST-Build
```

I had compared Gitlab and Drone configurations of the new project and the existed project, they are same.
I want to know how can i let the building go forward automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Project Settings
Protected => disable